# Chord Function Derivation

Tags: trigonometry

I am studing Trigonometry and got to work with chords. I find the Wikipedia derivation of the formula $2\sin\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right)$, but I couldn't figure out how to algebraically go from$\sqrt{2-2\cos\theta}$ to $2\sin\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right)?$ 
The process to find chord is: $$\operatorname{chord}(\theta)= \sqrt{(1-\cos\theta)^2+\sin^2\theta}=\sqrt{2-2\cos\theta}=2\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$The link from Wikipedia is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_(geometry)#In_trigonometry

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chord Formula derivation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3622733/chord-formula-derivation)

Comment: That was my Question, but once it got closed I just posted it again.

Comment: Yes, Sebastiano, it helped me understanding more about the derivation, but I just could realize the process now. Thank you indeed.

Comment: Reposting a question is not the way to circumvent closure. Instead, you should have edited the previous version in a way that convinced the community to reopen it. Voting to close.

Comment: I'm sorry, actually I edited it, but once I'm new here in the forum I badly decided to repost it. Now I realized it was the wrong decision.

Comment: I wasn't *scolding* you, just *informing* you. :) You'll do better next time. Welcome to the community!

Comment: I'm scolding me @Blue instead of you :-)  永輝123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sqrt{2-2\cos\theta}=\sqrt{2(1-\cos\theta)}=\sqrt{2\cdot 2\sin^2{\frac{\theta}{2}}}=2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$, which gives the desired result.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helps you.

Comment: Excuse me but where is the absolute value?